# Search in a string literal with a table field with peewee ORM

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, orm, peewee

I am trying to find all the records for which a certain field matches the beginning of a string literal provided as a fixed parameter. The *needle* is a field from a table.

Example: Given a parameter 'John Doe', I would like to get all the records of the table user, for which the first_name field is a sub-string of the beginning of that 'John Doe' string (e.g. matching records would be those for which the first_name is 'John', or 'Jo', or 'Joh', etc.

It seems I can achieve this with the following SQL:

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE 'John Doe' LIKE first_name || '%'`

Now how to translate that to peewee? It's strange that I am able to actually obtain the correct SQL for this but for some reason peewee is returning an empty result while the same query is working when I enter it directly via SQLite command line.

`User.select().where(SQL("'John Doe'").startswith(User.first_name))`

When I check the `sql()` of this, it shows:

`('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."first_name" FROM "user" AS "t1" WHERE ("John Doe" LIKE ("t1"."first_name" || ?))', ['%'])`

But the result is empty. Same SQL in the command line returns the right record... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would write it:

```
User.select().where(Value('John Doe') ** (User.first_name + '%'))
```

The exponentiation overload translates to case-insensitive LIKE.

Comment: Thanks! This `Value` is what I have been looking for!